# How to statically link missing libgcc_s_seh-1.dll and libstdc++-6.dll DLLs for 9.3-win32 MinGW executable

Tags: debian, windows, gcc, g++, mingw

I want to compile a simple Windows application on Linux using MinGW.

I compile as follows:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -L. -l:mathlib.dll -o fib main.cpp mathlib.h
```

This results in an executable `fib` that computes the N'th fibonacci number using a function imported from `mathlib.dll`.

Now, when executing `fib` on Windows, it complains that `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll` and `libstdc++-6.dll` are missing.

If I copy these DLLs to Windows, then everything works, but I'd like not to copy these MinGW dependencies with every executable.

How can I statically link these MinGW depencies, such that `foo` depends on no other DLLs than `mathlib.dll`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Build your program (and `mathlib.dll`, if necessary) with the `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` options:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -L. -l:mathlib.dll -o fib main.cpp mathlib.h
```

This will produce a binary with no external dependencies on `libgcc` and `libstdc++` DLLs.

Comment: Thank you. It works. However, I also had to compile the DLL with those options, otherwise I got an error for `fib.exe`, and it was not obvious that the error originated from the DLL (in fact nothing was mentioned about `mathlib.dll` in the error message). What `gcc` command do use to see those options (e.g. `static-libgcc`)? Nothing is shown for `gcc -v --help | grep static-libgcc`.

Comment: Yes, `mathlib.dll` would acquire its own dependencies on those DLLs if you build it using GCC without those options (I hadn’t realised you were building the DLL too). The options [are documented in the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) but don’t appear in the `--help` output.